# Excel VBA loop through range to find Type of FormatCondition

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, conditional-formatting

**My issue:**

I want to loop through a range, and whenever it finds a coloured cell, it should copy the cell to the left to the cell to the right of it. And then afterwards paste it into an other worksheet.

My sheet called “Compare” compares two sets of data, whereas a FormatConditions is applied as xlUniqueValues... The two sets of data, should contain the same data, but sometimes, there will be some, which are not within the other range. It is these cells that I am interested in finding with my loop, and then doping the processes if the criteria is met.

My code doesn't loop through the cells and returns me this message:

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

A screenshot of some of the data in Sheet "Compare":

[image: Screenshot of Sheet "Compare"]

**My Code:**

```
    Sub LoopForCondFormatCells()

    Dim sht3, sht4 As Worksheet
    Dim ColB, c As Range
    Set sht3 = Sheets("Compare")
    Set sht4 = Sheets("Print ready")

    ColB1 = sht3.Range("G3:G86")
    Set ColB = Range(ColB1)

   For Each c In ColB.Cells
   If c.FormatConditions.Type = xlUniqueValues Then 'Error here!
        CValue = c.Address(False, False, xlA1)
        CValueOffsetL = sht3.Range(CValue).Offset(0, -1).Address(False, False, xlA1)
        CValueOffsetR = sht3.Range(CValue).Offset(0, 1).Address(False, False, xlA1)
        sht3.Range(CValueOffsetL, CValueOffsetR).Copy
        KvikOffIns = sht4.Range(HosKvikOff).Offset(0, -1).Address(False, False, xlA1)
        sht4.Range(KvikOffIns).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        End If
    Next c
```

**Goal:**

I want the macro to loop through the cells, and find whatever cells, which has the FormatConditions type "xlUniqueValues". Whenever it comes across a cell, which is FormatConditions type "xlUniqueValues", it should do the steps:

```
CValue = c.Address(False, False, xlA1)
CValueOffsetL = sht3.Range(CValue).Offset(0, -1).Address(False, False, xlA1)
CValueOffsetR = sht3.Range(CValue).Offset(0, 1).Address(False, False, xlA1)
sht3.Range(CValueOffsetL, CValueOffsetR).Copy
KvikOffIns = sht4.Range(HosKvikOff).Offset(0, -1).Address(False, False, xlA1)
sht4.Range(KvikOffIns).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

What should I write in my "If c Is" line to get the macro to do what I want it to do?

Comment: You say "My code loops through the cells easily".  Frankly, I don't believe you.  `ColB1 = sht3.Range("G3:G86")` returns an Array (default Values property of range).  then `Set ColB = Range(ColB1)` where `ColB1` is an array, throughs an error: `1004`

Comment: That said, I'm not clear on what range you want to loop.  Can you specify the desired range please?

Comment: Sorry that was wrong... I edited it to the right thing... But the range is actually not a problem...

Comment: I'll get to the copy part once we sort the range loop,... because it _is_ a problem (among others)

Comment: Actually the desired range is set by variables for sht3... At the time of writing it is just "G3:G86", which it returns, so my laziness kicked in, and I didn't want to post to many things. My problem is that I don't know how to get VBA to look for the type?

Comment: And you should say which line causes the error

Comment: Since I have tried to loop through the cells within the range to find colors, which it looped through, but didn't return any value...

Comment: The Line that causes the error is the "If c.FormatConditions.Type = xlUniqueValues Then"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162667/discussion-between-patrick-s-and-chris-neilsen).

Answer (score 1):

There a a number of issues in your code

1. Declare all variables.  (Include `Option Explicit` at top of module to force this
2. Be specific on all declarations (`Dim sht3, sht4 As Worksheet` declares `sht3` as `Variant`)
3. Your method of referencing ranges is convoluted and confusing and unnecassary
4. `c.FormatConditions` is a Collection of conditional formats, and doesn't have a `Type`.  Iterate the collection and test the Type of each
5. You are copying everything, including the conditional formats.  Is that your intent?  If not, I'll update answer to show a different way

refactored code so far

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopForCondFormatCells()

    Dim sht3 As Worksheet, sht4 As Worksheet
    Dim ColB As Range, c As Range
    Dim ColB1 As Range

    Dim HosKvikOff As Range
    Dim n As Long

    Set sht3 = Worksheets("Compare")
    Set sht4 = Worksheets("Print ready")

    Set HosKvikOff = sht4.Range("A1")  ' <-- update to suit

    Set ColB1 = sht3.Range("G3:G86")

    For Each c In ColB1.Cells
        With c.FormatConditions
            For n = 1 To .Count
                If .Item(n).Type = xlUniqueValues Then
                    c.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 3).Copy
                    HosKvikOff.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                    Set HosKvikOff = HosKvikOff.Offset(1, 0)  ' Increment output row
                End If
            Next

        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

---

A method not relying of Conditional Formatting

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopForCondFormatCells()
    Dim sht3 As Worksheet, sht4 As Worksheet
    Dim ColB As Range, c As Range
    Dim ColB1 As Range

    Dim HosKvikOff As Range
    Dim n As Long

    Set sht3 = Worksheets("Compare")
    Set sht4 = Worksheets("Print ready")

    Set HosKvikOff = sht4.Range("A1")

    Set ColB1 = sht3.Range("G3:G86")

    ' Copy Non-duplicates
    For Each c In ColB1.Cells
        If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
            n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ColB1, c)
            If n = 1 Then
                c.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 3).Copy
                HosKvikOff.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                Set HosKvikOff = HosKvikOff.Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This code makes me able to loop through the cells... But also returns every cells within the range.

Comment: "sht3" is a compare sheet, where it compares 2 different sets of data... If it find a unique value, it will color it, but as of what I can see, the code you have listed inserts every single row in ColB1... Am I not able to return just the one cell, which is unique, or should I reference both ranges, but somehow implement that it should only take the data from ColB1??

Comment: `ConditionalFormat.Type` tell you that a `xlUniqueValues` condition exists, not whether it has been triggered.  Why are you wanting to test the CF, and not just test directly for unique?

Comment: I'm not that experienced with searching for this in VBA... I just want to copy the line(s) that has triggered the "xlUniqueValues" condition, whereas I thought that FormatCondition.Type would help, or something near that, but now I can see that it doesn't :)

Comment: Do you have any ideas, of how I can get my code to do what I want? And is it even possible?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using (there is a new property available in Office 365)?

Comment: I am using 365 on my workcomputer, but right now I am trying to make it better on my laptop (private) which runs 2013 :)

Comment: I still think it's better to avoid the whole testing CF thing and look at the source data.  If you give details of the raw data I can advise

Comment: Give me just a couple of minutes and I'll have a sheet up for you in just a second :)

Comment: Uhm just a quick question... I have named the sheets for your sake in English on this site, within my code... But would it do anything, if name, that I refer to is in Danish?? :)

Comment: Well it's actually just the lines where I say .Find("Bogføringsdato") or something like that... So it's some headers, or just the sheets names, which is in Danish, everything else within the code is in English :)

Comment: That should be ok

Comment: Here's the link for my OneDrive: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsQuasddi71ugRqHjco1z_ZEqKnC       Just to let you know beforehand... It is a pretty long code, which the entire sheet contains, and I haven't split it up into part subs, since I just started doing VBA stuff for a couple of months ago... But what you're helping me with, is in the bottom

Comment: When I use this code, I still get all values within G3:G86? :)

Comment: Then they must be all unique.   To test, put this formula in a blank cell on row 3 and copy down.  `=COUNTIFS($G$3:$G$86,G3)`  Any that return `1` will be copied (`TÆL.HVISER($G$3:$G$86,G3)` in danish)

Comment: Uhm... I might not have been saying it well enough... Sorry. But in sht3. There are two sets of data, from sheet 1 and sheet 2... The CF has been made og column G and column B, if there are any mismatches. So singlehandedly the columns will be uniques... Could I somehow say it should look in both ranges, but only return the value from ColB1?

Comment: So, `=COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$86,G3)`  ie how many times does `G3` occur in `B3:B86`

Comment: G3's value only occurs once in column B... If it doesn't it's Unique and will return a background colour on the cell... But is it possible to say "For Each c in Range("B3:B88","G3:G86"), but then only returning the value, if it is range G?

Comment: For non-contiguous ranges, you need to loop over the Areas and Range collections.  Eg `Set rng = Range("B3:B88","G3:G86") Dim Arr as Area For each Arr in rng.Areas For each c in Arr.Cells ... Next c Next Arr`

Comment: Some sample data and expected results would help

Comment: Dude :) The sample data is within the link I have listed in some comments above, OneDrive

Comment: Sorry, but you are not making sense.  The sheet containing conditional formatting is `Afstemning` and there is no data in that sheet.  I don't yet understand your criteria for copying

Comment: Then it’s because you haven’t run the code yet (Module1)